# Jquery backgroundPosition plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, internet-explorer-8, background, jquery-animate

i'm using a plugin by Alexander Farkas which animates backgrounds really nicely.

And it works fine even in IE9, but in IE8 and IE7 gives me this error: 'SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'replace': object is null or undefined'

Somehow in IE8 he cant transform the values (by values i mean the pixels) given to the function...

Could somebody have a look? i didn't want to post the hole js but you can check it out here:

http://factorystore.hu/test/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure there will be no trailing comma's IE doesn't like trailing commas in arrays/objects.

check these two lines

```
start = toArray(start);
 var end = toArray(fx.end);
```

**Updated Solutions**

paste this code

```
if(!document.defaultView || !document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){ // IE6-IE8
        var oldCurCSS = jQuery.curCSS;
        jQuery.curCSS = function(elem, name, force){
            if(name === 'background-position'){
                name = 'backgroundPosition';
            }
            if(name !== 'backgroundPosition' || !elem.currentStyle || elem.currentStyle[ name ]){
                return oldCurCSS.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            var style = elem.style;
            if ( !force && style && style[ name ] ){
                return style[ name ];
            }
            return oldCurCSS(elem, 'backgroundPositionX', force) +' '+ oldCurCSS(elem, 'backgroundPositionY', force);
        };
    }
```

above this line

```
$.extend($.fx.step,{
```

Comment: but how should i do that in this case ?

Comment: i have updated my code please check these two lines and try to get values of start and end in case of ie

Comment: yes the problem is there, the start value for example is [0, "px", 0, "px"] and [0, "px", -520, "px"], and even IE9 gives me these values but IE8 give back the error i mentioned at the begining. so somehow he cant play nice with replace and match.. at least so i think

Comment: Thank you verry much, it works now, only in IE8 but that's ok to... thanks a lot

Comment: it works in IE7 to... :) i only need to correct the z-index somehow... so thanks again super great :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18177/discussion-between-rahul-and-mr-sam)

Comment: @Mr.Sam can we have a discussion in chat